# How to show to user decrypted password by user_pass in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I need to show on page user password by user_pass

I use this code:

```
$user = get_user_by('login', $username);
echo 'User password is ' . $user->user_pass;
```

But this function show me encrypted password, help me please to show user password decrypted on page.

Comment: You can't "decrypt" stored passwords in WordPress because *WordPress doesn't store encrypted passwords at all*. it stores hashed passwords. Hashing is a one-way operation.

Comment: **Also, you should never build a feature like this into a program**. Tell your boss/client to read a book on elementary infosec.